# How to test a webservice / WSDL

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl

I have generated this WSDL file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://math/" name="MathServicesService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://math/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://math/" schemaLocation="MathServicesService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="addTwoInts">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:addTwoInts"/>
  </message>
  <message name="addTwoIntsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:addTwoIntsResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="multiplyTwoFloats">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:multiplyTwoFloats"/>
  </message>
  <message name="multiplyTwoFloatsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:multiplyTwoFloatsResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="MathServices">
    <operation name="addTwoInts">
      <input message="tns:addTwoInts"/>
      <output message="tns:addTwoIntsResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="multiplyTwoFloats">
      <input message="tns:multiplyTwoFloats"/>
      <output message="tns:multiplyTwoFloatsResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="MathServicesPortBinding" type="tns:MathServices">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="addTwoInts">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="multiplyTwoFloats">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="MathServicesService">
    <port name="MathServicesPort" binding="tns:MathServicesPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

from this class...

```
package math;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class MathServices {

    public int addTwoInts(int int1, int int2){
        return int1+int2;
    }

    public float multiplyTwoFloats(float float1, float float2){
        return float1 * float2;
    }
}
```

How can I test to see if this webservice is working properly using the WSDL? I don't understand how the functionality (`int1+int2` and `float1*float2`) translates to the XML. All I see in the WSDL are what translate to method names and parameter names. I don't see where the math goes on. :/

That said, where do the parameters come from when using the webservice? How do you even use the webservice? Can I just use it through my browser?

Comment: you don't see the math in the WSDL, because there isn't any. It's just a formal declaration of all your functions, parameters and return types. It's still your Java code that does the math in the backend.

Comment: So how are the parameters passed to the code? Obviously you're not invoking the methods and passing parameters directly; where do they come from?

Comment: WSDL will tell all that I said before and also the concrete binding, i.e. in case of HTTP, URLs and methods to be called and where your parameters will be passed. I am not trying to answer your question, it's just a note on WSDL since you said you were looking for the code there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For soap you can use SoapUI. See http://www.soapui.org/.

Comment: There is a lot of resources see http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/functional-testing.html for example.

Comment: What am I supposed to use for the Service endpoint? that is where I'm confused.

Comment: General note on SOAP-UI: it does not validate the input or the output against the wsdl automatically, so it is possible to send and receive xml that does not conform to the wsdl.

Comment: And this is exactly the reason why you shouldn't just provide the link. Link rot has resulted in Getting-Started link to be completely useless.

Comment: @Volodya people can put some effort to find out the link has move to http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/functional-testing.html, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can test WSDLs with [SoapUI](http://www.eviware.com/soapUI/what-is-soapui.html).